# Re-usable input file with react-hook-form logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, controlled-component

I'm trying to build a reusable input file as per below.

```js
function InputFileControl({ control, name, initialValue, ...rest }) {
  const {
    field: { ref, ...inputProps },
    fieldState: { invalid, error, isTouched },
  } = useController({
    name,
    control,
    rules: { required: true },
    defaultValue: initialValue,
  })
  return (
    <StyledGrid>
      <Grid item container>
        <input {...inputProps} inputRef={ref} {...rest} />
      </Grid>
      <Collapse in={invalid}>
        <Grid item container>
          <StyledAlert severity="error">{error && error.message}</StyledAlert>
        </Grid>
      </Collapse>
    </StyledGrid>
  )
}
```

For usage, where my form is declared, this is how i'm using it:

```js
<InputFileControl control={control} name="file" type="file" />
```

Unfortunately, It is not working. When i submit the form, the file is only the path. There is no files[0] to manage.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get something like `C:\\fakepath\<filename>`

Here is a possible solution: [React Hook Form with file just submitting fakepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038076/react-hook-form-with-file-just-submitting-fakepath)

Comment: Exactly. i was getting that C:\\fakepath\<filename>  .  With you help i found the solution here: [link] https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sun-nsfbk?file=/src/App.js:379-480 [/link] . Now it woks fine. Thanks a lot Joris.